# array reading in laravel 8 blade with foreach loop

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried to use blade in Laravel 8

after sending the array by compact like that

```
Route::get('about', function () {

    $Cards = [ 'one' , 'tow' , 'three'];
    return view('about', compact('Cards'));
});
```

I read it in the html page like that :

```
 @foreach ($Cards as $card)
       
      <li>{{ $card }}</li>
    
     @endforeach
```

but I get the html text without execute the for each loop

```
@foreach ($Cards as $card)
<li>{{ $card }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you sure you named your file `about.blade.php` and not just `about.php`?

Comment: Did you use the `@foreach ... @endforeach` loop in a .html page or a .blade.php page?

Comment: the problem was because of naming the file just "about.php" without ".blade", I did not know why actually.

Comment: @Infinity you might get your answer here [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade)